# How curl php this is bash

Tags: php, curl

```
'Origin: http://vehiculos.valledelcauca.gov.co','Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36' -H 'HC: 910141113' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://vehiculos.valledelcauca.gov.co/post_smart_valle_prod/www/com.aspsolutions.GWTJSuite/8E997CB2F1E5E2F7BF75687812584FF1.cache.html' -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=D949D5A5B78EA4EEF453283118D0D5C7' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary '<C1 N1="com.smart.src.taxvalle.taxinva.taxinva" HC="910141113" CP="F" MOC="LCSP" ><XD SI="" ><D N="DCRITERIOS" ><R ID="0" ST="I" ><F N="SuimNi01" V="JWF579" /></R></D><D N="DWEB" ><R ID="0" ST="I" /></D></XD><XV E4="29" MOC="LCSP" NTF="DCRITERIOS.LCSP" CP="F" /><M1 N1="processEvent" /></C1>' --compressed
```

I do not know how to do this curl, I tried several things, but I do not see how to post that binary data. I would like to help you.

this is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//$urlfija="https://consulta.simit.org.co/Simit/";
$ur2 = "http://vehiculos.valledelcauca.gov.co/post_smart_valle_prod/FrameworkServlet";


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ur2);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'BIGipServerPOOL_WEBLOGIC=1157784586.15900.0000; path=/; Httponly');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '<C1 N1="com.smart.src.taxvalle.taxinva.taxinva" HC="910141113" CP="F" MOC="LCSP" ><XD SI="" ><D N="DCRITERIOS" ><R ID="0" ST="I" ><F N="SuimNi01" V="JWF579" /></R></D><D N="DWEB" ><R ID="0" ST="I" /></D></XD><XV E4="29" MOC="LCSP" NTF="DCRITERIOS.LCSP" CP="F" /><M1 N1="processEvent" /></C1>');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Origin: http://vehiculos.valledelcauca.gov.co',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
'HC: 910141113',
'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
'Accept: */*',
'Referer: http://vehiculos.valledelcauca.gov.co/post_smart_valle_prod/www/com.aspsolutions.GWTJSuite/8E997CB2F1E5E2F7BF75687812584FF1.cache.html',
'Cookie: JSESSIONID=D949D5A5B78EA4EEF453283118D0D5C7',
'Connection: keep-alive'

    ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);


$responsea11 = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);
```

please help me

Answer (score 2):

curl is not able to write PHP code for you, specifically, but it IS capable of writing C code for you, using the --libcurl  parameter. and its usually pretty easy to translate that code from C to PHP. (as a bonus, PHP and C looks much alike, so if you're used to PHP syntax, C syntax is not difficult to read). unfortunately, your curl command is incomplete, so fixing that, i get `curl -H 'Origin: http://vehiculos.valledelcauca.gov.co','Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36' -H 'HC: 910141113' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://vehiculos.valledelcauca.gov.co/post_smart_valle_prod/www/com.aspsolutions.GWTJSuite/8E997CB2F1E5E2F7BF75687812584FF1.cache.html' -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=D949D5A5B78EA4EEF453283118D0D5C7' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary '<C1 N1="com.smart.src.taxvalle.taxinva.taxinva" HC="910141113" CP="F" MOC="LCSP" ><XD SI="" ><D N="DCRITERIOS" ><R ID="0" ST="I" ><F N="SuimNi01" V="JWF579" /></R></D><D N="DWEB" ><R ID="0" ST="I" /></D></XD><XV E4="29" MOC="LCSP" NTF="DCRITERIOS.LCSP" CP="F" /><M1 N1="processEvent" /></C1>' --compressed http://example.org` , now adding `--libcurl test.c` gives me

```
/********* Sample code generated by the curl command line tool **********
 * All curl_easy_setopt() options are documented at:
 * https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html
 ************************************************************************/
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CURLcode ret;
  CURL *hnd;
  struct curl_slist *slist1;

  slist1 = NULL;
  slist1 = curl_slist_append(slist1, "Origin: http://vehiculos.valledelcauca.gov.co,Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
  slist1 = curl_slist_append(slist1, "Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8");
  slist1 = curl_slist_append(slist1, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");
  slist1 = curl_slist_append(slist1, "HC: 910141113");
  slist1 = curl_slist_append(slist1, "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
  slist1 = curl_slist_append(slist1, "Accept: */*");
  slist1 = curl_slist_append(slist1, "Referer: http://vehiculos.valledelcauca.gov.co/post_smart_valle_prod/www/com.aspsolutions.GWTJSuite/8E997CB2F1E5E2F7BF75687812584FF1.cache.html");
  slist1 = curl_slist_append(slist1, "Cookie: JSESSIONID=D949D5A5B78EA4EEF453283118D0D5C7");
  slist1 = curl_slist_append(slist1, "Connection: keep-alive");

  hnd = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.org");
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "<C1 N1=\"com.smart.src.taxvalle.taxinva.taxinva\" HC=\"910141113\" CP=\"F\" MOC=\"LCSP\" ><XD SI=\"\" ><D N=\"DCRITERIOS\" ><R ID=\"0\" ST=\"I\" ><F N=\"SuimNi01\" V=\"JWF579\" /></R></D><D N=\"DWEB\" ><R ID=\"0\" ST=\"I\" /></D></XD><XV E4=\"29\" MOC=\"LCSP\" NTF=\"DCRITERIOS.LCSP\" CP=\"F\" /><M1 N1=\"processEvent\" /></C1>");
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)291);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.52.1");
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist1);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 50L);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, (long)CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "");
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_SSH_KNOWNHOSTS, "/root/.ssh/known_hosts");
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);

  /* Here is a list of options the curl code used that cannot get generated
     as source easily. You may select to either not use them or implement
     them yourself.

  CURLOPT_WRITEDATA set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_INTERLEAVEDATA set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
  CURLOPT_READDATA set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_READFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
  CURLOPT_SEEKDATA set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_SEEKFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
  CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_STDERR set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
  CURLOPT_HEADERDATA set to a objectpointer

  */

  ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);

  curl_easy_cleanup(hnd);
  hnd = NULL;
  curl_slist_free_all(slist1);
  slist1 = NULL;

  return (int)ret;
}
/**** End of sample code ****/
```

now, slist translates to `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE` can be skipped (libcurl, or at least the php wrapper for it, will figure it out automatically), php sets NOPROGRESS automatically, most of it translates to php pretty easily.

translating it (manually) to PHP, we get

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
$ch = curl_init ( '' );

curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                "Origin: http://vehiculos.valledelcauca.gov.co,Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate", // NOTE: Accept-Encoding is probably a typo and should not be there, but its in OP's curl -H command, so... what do i know
                "Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8",
                "HC: 910141113",
                "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
                "Accept: */*", // actually, curl sends this by default on HTTP(S), so theres no need to set it manually
                "Referer: http://vehiculos.valledelcauca.gov.co/post_smart_valle_prod/www/com.aspsolutions.GWTJSuite/8E997CB2F1E5E2F7BF75687812584FF1.cache.html",
                "Cookie: JSESSIONID=D949D5A5B78EA4EEF453283118D0D5C7" 

        ),
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://example.org',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '<C1 N1=\"com.smart.src.taxvalle.taxinva.taxinva\" HC=\"910141113\" CP=\"F\" MOC=\"LCSP\" ><XD SI=\"\" ><D N=\"DCRITERIOS\" ><R ID=\"0\" ST=\"I\" ><F N=\"SuimNi01\" V=\"JWF579\" /></R></D><D N=\"DWEB\" ><R ID=\"0\" ST=\"I\" /></D></XD><XV E4=\"29\" MOC=\"LCSP\" NTF=\"DCRITERIOS.LCSP\" CP=\"F\" /><M1 N1=\"processEvent\" /></C1>',
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '', // this is --compressed
        CURLOPT_SSH_KNOWNHOSTS => '/root/.ssh/known_hosts',
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true  // good for debugging.
) );
curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close($ch);
```

note that i mentioned some TECHNICALLY VALID, but probable errors in the comments, also since your curl command didn't include the url to fetch, i added example.org, also, /root/.ssh/known_hosts is specific to my machine, you probably want to alter it (or set CURLOPT_VERIFYPEER=>false,CURLOPT_VERIFYHOST=>false and it wont bother validating the SSL cert at all)

Comment: Friend, thank you very much for replying, it is not too much to say that you are a connoisseur of php